# How to find key-value pairs for 'data' dictionary in session.post() request

Tags: python-3.x, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've managed (with help from the StackOverflow community) to write a script to scrape a real estate webpage. One key part of this is `requests.post(html, data=data)`, as in:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import requests

# get homepage session
session = requests.Session()
homepage = session.get('https://www.mlslistings.com/') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(homepage.content, "html.parser")
        
# get security token, post search data
token = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']
data = {'transactionType': 'buy', 'listing_status': 'Active', 'searchTextType': '', 'searchText': '94618','__RequestVerificationToken': token, 'property_type': 'SingleFamilyResidence'}
search_results = session.post("https://www.mlslistings.com/Search/ResultPost", data=data)
tree = html.fromstring(search_results.content)
```

This works just fine, but I wouldn't be able to do it again for another webpage on my own. So I have a couple questions:

1. How to find the names of keys and the corresponding values in the `data` dictionary? I've inspected html elements of the page and am having trouble locating these.
2. Does one always add `/Search/ResultPost` to the webpage URL for the `session.post()` request? It doesn't seem to work if I remove it, but I don't know where it came from or if this will apply to all webpages I try to scrape in the future.

Comment: It comes from learning to inspect the webtraffic that goes back and forth between client and server. You can do this with specific tools e.g. WireShark, Fiddler, or via F12 in your browser > dev tools > network tab. Often, particularly with dynamic content pages you will find that content is loaded via xhr using GET/POST ...that you can track down and mimic - as has been done, I suspect, in the answer you show above.

Comment: The pairs of values would be listed in the recorded activity for that request as well as header info, the endpoint etc.....

Comment: Thank you. In Chrome, for `mlslistings.com`, I'm able to go to `F12` > `Network` > select top item (`www.mlslistings.com`) under `Name` > click on `Response` tab, and find the names of keys and values buried in a long html script. If I try the same for another webpage (`www.realtor.com`) I see a short html script and no clear key-value pairs. Can you help me find them here?